# I'd like some books similar to “Advanced Problems in Mathematics: Preparing for University”

Tags: euclidean-geometry, book-recommendation

I enjoyed
*Advanced Problems in Mathematics: Preparing for University* by Stephen Siklos? Can anyone recommend similar books?

Comment: What kind of books are you looking for?

Comment: @AliBasil Welcome To MSE ! Kindly add relevent context and Your knowledge background in mathematics and specify more about the book you mentioned.